# Store post meta key into an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to retrieve the _octopus_id postmeta and store that into the ids array, what am I doing wrong?

```php
    $ids = [];
    var_dump($ids);

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'offices',
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'        => '_octopus_id',
                'value'      => $ids,
            ),
        )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Update: I've got the offices stored in an array, but I can't figure out how to get the post meta key _octopus_id only out of the office and store that within ids.

```php
    /* Set the WP offices in an array */
    $ids = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'office',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'        => '_octopus_id',
            ),
        )
    ]);

    $posts[] = $ids->posts;

    var_dump($posts);
    var_dump(is_array($posts));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to get the content with the query and then loop it and fill the array. What you do, is trying to fetch the content by the value which is null in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I went ahead and updated the post.